# Back face culling in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I am currently trying to set up a rotating ball in scene kit. I have created the ball and applied a texture to it.

```
ballMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: ballTexture)
ballMaterial.doubleSided = true
ballGeometry.materials = [ballMaterial]
```

The current ballTexture is a semi-transparent texture as I am hoping to see the back face roll around.

However I get some strange culling where only half of the back facing polygons are shown even though the doubleSided property is set to true.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This happens because the effects of transparency are draw-order dependent. SceneKit doesn't know to draw the back-facing polygons of the sphere before the front-facing ones. (In fact, it can't really do that without reorganizing the vertex buffers on the GPU for every frame, which would be a huge drag on render performance.)

The vertex layout for an `SCNSphere` has it set up like the lat/long grid on a globe: the triangles render in order along the meridians from 0° to 360°, so depending on how the sphere is oriented with respect to the camera, some of the faces on the far side of the sphere will render before the nearer ones.

To fix this, you need to force the rendering order — either directly, or through the depth buffer. Here's one way to do that, using a separate material for the inside surface to illustrate the difference.

```
// add two balls, one a child of the other
let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 1))
let node2 = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 1))
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
node.addChildNode(node2)

// cull back-facing polygons on the first ball
// so we only see the outside
let mat1 = node.geometry!.firstMaterial!
mat1.cullMode = .Back
mat1.transparent.contents = bwCheckers
// my "bwCheckers" uses black for transparent, white for opaque
mat1.transparencyMode = .RGBZero

// cull front-facing polygons on the second ball
// so we only see the inside
let mat2 = node2.geometry!.firstMaterial!
mat2.cullMode = .Front
mat2.diffuse.contents = rgCheckers

// sphere normals face outward, so to make the inside respond
// to lighting, we need to invert them
let shader = "_geometry.normal *= -1.0;"
mat2.shaderModifiers = [SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry: shader]
```

[image: 2-sided ball]

(The shader modifier bit at the end isn't required — it just makes the inside material get diffuse shading. You could just as well use a material property that doesn't involve normals or lighting, like `emission`, depending on the look you want.)

You can also do this using a single node with a double-sided material by disabling [`writesToDepthBuffer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNMaterial_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNMaterial/writesToDepthBuffer), but that could also lead to undesirable interactions with the rest of your scene content — you might also need to mess with [`renderingOrder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNNode/renderingOrder) in that case.

Comment: Thanks for this. I suspected I would need to create two objects with front and back culling.

Comment: I didn't think about the shader, look great now!

Answer (score 0):

macOS 10.13 and iOS 11 added [SCNTransparencyMode.dualLayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntransparencymode/duallayer) which as far as I can tell doesn't even require setting `isDoubleSided` to true (the documentation doesn't provide any information at all). So a simple solution that's working for me would be:

```
ballMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: ballTexture)
ballMaterial.transparencyMode = .dualLayer  
ballGeometry.materials = [ballMaterial]
```